# How to redirect a page in sightly without html tags. Apart from "meta" command

Tags: sightly

I need to know about the redirection happen in sightly. Can someone help me with the code. I dont want  http://www.indiana.edu/~account/new-directory">  as this will be configured in head of html.

For me requirement in sightly.

Answer (score 3):

Sightly is a templating language only!

If you want a redirect, implement it in your controller Java class.

See Request Response API for that. https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/SlingHttpServletResponse.html

The WCMUse classes have access to the response object, here is the API : https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/adobe/cq/sightly/WCMUse.html

The redirection after that is just pure Java Servlet redirection.

Hope this will help.